# Silverlight FileInfo DataContext for TextBox

Tags: .net, silverlight

I have a textbox in silverlight that is defined as follows.

```
<TextBox x:Name="hedtextBox" DataContext="{Binding HedFileInfo}" Text="{Binding Name}" Width="100" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2,0,2,0" />
```

My viewmodel has a `FileInfo` object called `HedFileInfo`. And, I have a `Button` beside the textbox which, when clicked, launches the `OpenFileDialog` as follows

```
    private void HedBrowseButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var ofd = new OpenFileDialog { Filter = "CSV Files (.csv)|*.csv" };
        var result = ofd.ShowDialog();
        // Process open file dialog box results
        if (result != true) return;
        hedTextBox.DataContext = ofd.File;
    }
```

I'm doing all this because silverlight doesnt let me access the `FullName` in `OpenFileDialog` for all paths(network drives etc). And if I just bind a `string` in the `ViewModel` to the `TextBox`, I wont be able to get the full path in the string. 
The `TextBox` text binds to the `Name` field, but when I set the DataContext  in the button click event, the FileInfo in the viewmodel is not updating
Does this make sense?

Comment: Ok... Now what is your question?

Comment: Does it make sense? Because its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've come to the correct answer yourself.  If you want the property on the Source object (the `HedFileInfo`) to change when the `DataContext` property is modified you need to change the binding mode to `TwoWay`.  This is perfectly normal and how its supposed to work.

Consider the most basic of bindings:-

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Description}" />
```

This code has set a binding on the `TextBox` object for its `TextProperty` dependency propery.  Whenever the `Description` property changes this binding will assign the value of `Description` to the `TextBox.Text` property.  However there are two other ways to set the `Text` property.  The user can type over what it is currently present or code can assign a value to the `Text` property.  It is therefore possible for the `TextBox.Text` property to have a different value from the `Description`.  In the default `OneWay` mode the `Description` property on the source object is not modified.

Now change to:-

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Description, Mode-TwoWay}" />
```

Whenever the user enters new text or code modifies the `Text` property directly the binding will now respond by updating the `Description` property on the source object.

The `DataContext` property and the binding thereof behaves exactly the same way.  With:-

```
 <TextBox DataContext="{Binding HedFileInfo}" Text="{Binding Name}" />
```

Whenever the value of `HedFileInfo` changes in the source view model (assuming `INotifyPropertyChanged` is implemented) then the value of `DataContext` will be changed.  However when code modifies the value of `DataContext` directly the binding (being in `OneWay` mode) does not update the source view model.

Change it to this:-

```
 <TextBox DataContext="{Binding HedFileInfo, Mode=TwoWay}" Text="{Binding Name}" />
```

and now it works as you would like it to.  When code changes the `DataContext` value directly the binding will respond by updating the `HedFileInfo` property of the source view model.

Comment: Thank you. Is this an acceptable way to deal with openfiledialog's in mvvm?

Comment: @Aks: Personally I don't like rule making for using MVVM.  The real question is, if using Unit Tests is this testable if not are there reasonable alternatives (which with FileInfo can be tricky). If MVVM is being used to support the Designer/Developer separation do the designers object to this necessary code (you don't have much choice in aquiring a FileInfo).  That said personally I'd be inclined to create a new `FileDialogButton` control that has a `SelectedFile` dependency property.  That way the view doesn't need special code its in `FileDialogButton` and binding is simpler.